# 2010 SP1 Upgrade throws XPathException: Expression must evaluate to a node-set

Tags: 2010, upgrade

I'm stuck with an exception during upgrading SharePoint 2010 to SP1. It happens during provisioning of the central administration web app. I initially ran the configuration wizard and got the exception there.

After finding out where the configuration wizard failed (during Central Administration provisioning), I ran that portion via powershell in the hope it would give me more debug information.

Here's the output:

```
PS C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\BIN> .\PSCONFIG.EXE -cmd
adminvs -provision
SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard version 14.0.6009.1000. Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation
2010. All rights reserved.

Performing configuration task 1 of 3
Initializing SharePoint Products configuration...

Successfully initialized the SharePoint Products configuration.

Performing configuration task 2 of 3
Provisioning the SharePoint Central Administration Web Application...

Failed to provision the SharePoint Central Administration Web Application.

An exception of type System.Xml.XPath.XPathException was thrown.  Additional exception information:
Expression must evaluate to a node-set.

Total number of configuration settings run: 2
Total number of successful configuration settings: 1
Total number of unsuccessful configuration settings: 1
Successfully stopped the configuration of SharePoint Products.
Configuration of SharePoint Products failed.  Configuration must be performed before you use SharePoint Products.  For further details, see the diagnostic log located at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS\PSCDiagnostics_11_19_2011_16_27_23_438_492167605.log
and the application event log.
PS C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\BIN>
```

I looked at the log file but it doesn't tell me anything useful. Maybe some of you can decipher the problem?

```
    11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  ERR              Task adminvs has failed with an unknown exception 
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  ERR              Exception: System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.
   at System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator.Select(XPathExpression expr)
   at System.Xml.XmlNode.SelectSingleNode(String xpath)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigFileChanges.ApplyModificationsWebConfigXmlDocument(XmlDocument xdWebConfig, String filepath)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.ApplyWebConfigModifications()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.Provision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationWebApplication.Provision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebServiceInstance.Provision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.CentralAdministrationSiteTask.ProvisionAdminVs()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.CentralAdministrationSiteTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF              Entering function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                  Resource id to be retrieved is ExceptionInfo for language English (United States)
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                  Resource retrieved id ExceptionInfo is An exception of type {0} was thrown.  Additional exception information: {1}
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF              Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF              Entering function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                Entering function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                  Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                    Resource id to be retrieved is ExceptionInfo for language English (United States)
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                    Resource retrieved id ExceptionInfo is An exception of type {0} was thrown.  Additional exception information: {1}
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                  Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF              Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  ERR              An exception of type System.Xml.XPath.XPathException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.
System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.
   at System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator.Select(XPathExpression expr)
   at System.Xml.XmlNode.SelectSingleNode(String xpath)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigFileChanges.ApplyModificationsWebConfigXmlDocument(XmlDocument xdWebConfig, String filepath)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.ApplyWebConfigModifications()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.Provision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationWebApplication.Provision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebServiceInstance.Provision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.CentralAdministrationSiteTask.ProvisionAdminVs()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.CentralAdministrationSiteTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF              Entering function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                Entering function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                  Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                    Resource id to be retrieved is ExceptionInfo for language English (United States)
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                    Resource retrieved id ExceptionInfo is An exception of type {0} was thrown.  Additional exception information: {1}
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                  Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF              Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF              Entering function get CommandCollection.this[string key]
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                  Found value in collection for key global
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                Found command global in collection
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF              Leaving function get CommandCollection.this[string key]
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF              Entering function get CommandCollection.this[string key]
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                  Found value in collection for key initialize
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                Found command initialize in collection
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF              Leaving function get CommandCollection.this[string key]
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF              Entering function Command.this[string key]
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                  Found value in collection for key SINGLESERVER
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                Found parameter SINGLESERVER in collection
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF              Leaving function Command.this[string key]
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF              Entering function Command.this[string key]
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                  Found value in collection for key upgradesessionid
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                Found parameter upgradesessionid in collection
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF              Leaving function Command.this[string key]
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF              Entering function TaskBase.OnTaskStop
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                Creating the OnTaskStop event for task adminvs
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  ERR                Task adminvs has failed
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                friendlyMessage for task adminvs is An exception of type System.Xml.XPath.XPathException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                debugMessage for task adminvs is An exception of type System.Xml.XPath.XPathException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.
System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.
   at System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator.Select(XPathExpression expr)
   at System.Xml.XmlNode.SelectSingleNode(String xpath)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigFileChanges.ApplyModificationsWebConfigXmlDocument(XmlDocument xdWebConfig, String filepath)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.ApplyWebConfigModifications()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.Provision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationWebApplication.Provision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebServiceInstance.Provision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.CentralAdministrationSiteTask.ProvisionAdminVs()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.CentralAdministrationSiteTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                Entering function TaskBase.FireTaskStateChanged
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                  Firing the OnTaskStateChanged event for task adminvs
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                  Entering function TaskDriver.TaskStateEventHandler
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                    Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                      Resource id to be retrieved is AdministrationVirtualServerTaskDisplayName for language English (United States)
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                      Resource retrieved id AdministrationVirtualServerTaskDisplayName is SharePoint Central Administration Web Application
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                    Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                    Received an TaskStateEventHandler event.  task:adminvs TaskBase.State:stopped
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                    Entering function TasksQueue.IncrementTaskFailed
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                      Incremented the number of tasks failed to 1
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                    Leaving function TasksQueue.IncrementTaskFailed
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                    Task adminvs has stopped and failed.  Total failed is now 1
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                  Leaving function TaskDriver.TaskStateEventHandler
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                  Entering function CommandLine.TaskStateEventHandler
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                    Received an TaskStateEventHandler event.  task:adminvs TaskBase.State:stopped
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                    Task adminvs has stopped and failed.  Total failed is now 1
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                    Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                      Resource id to be retrieved is AdministrationVirtualServerTaskFailConfigDisplayLabel for language English (United States)
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                      Resource retrieved id AdministrationVirtualServerTaskFailConfigDisplayLabel is Failed to provision the SharePoint Central Administration Web Application.
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                    Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                    Last message from task adminvs is An exception of type System.Xml.XPath.XPathException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                  Leaving function CommandLine.TaskStateEventHandler
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF                Leaving function TaskBase.FireTaskStateChanged
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF              Leaving function TaskBase.OnTaskStop
11/19/2011 16:27:30  8  INF            Leaving function TaskThread.ExecuteTask
11/19/2011 16:27:30  1  INF            Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
11/19/2011 16:27:30  1  INF              Resource id to be retrieved is AdministrationVirtualServerTaskDisplayName for language English (United States)
11/19/2011 16:27:30  1  INF              Resource retrieved id AdministrationVirtualServerTaskDisplayName is SharePoint Central Administration Web Application
11/19/2011 16:27:30  1  INF            Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
11/19/2011 16:27:30  1  ERR            Task SharePoint Central Administration Web Application failed, so stopping execution of the engine
11/19/2011 16:27:30  1  INF            Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
11/19/2011 16:27:30  1  INF              Resource id to be retrieved is AdministrationVirtualServerTaskFailConfigDisplayLabel for language English (United States)
11/19/2011 16:27:30  1  INF              Resource retrieved id AdministrationVirtualServerTaskFailConfigDisplayLabel is Failed to provision the SharePoint Central Administration Web Application.
11/19/2011 16:27:30  1  INF            Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
11/19/2011 16:27:30  1  ERR            Failed to provision the SharePoint Central Administration Web Application.
An exception of type System.Xml.XPath.XPathException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.
System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.
   at System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator.Select(XPathExpression expr)
   at System.Xml.XmlNode.SelectSingleNode(String xpath)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigFileChanges.ApplyModificationsWebConfigXmlDocument(XmlDocument xdWebConfig, String filepath)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.ApplyWebConfigModifications()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.Provision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationWebApplication.Provision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebServiceInstance.Provision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.CentralAdministrationSiteTask.ProvisionAdminVs()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.CentralAdministrationSiteTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
```

Has any of you experienced the same thing? Do you have a solution to share about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in the log, the error happens in conjunction with:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.ApplyWebConfigModifications()
```

To solve the problem I grabbed central administration web app via powershell and saw that some web.config modifications on that object (`$ca.WebConfigModifications`) weren't kosher. I removed (`$ca.WebConfigModifications.Remove($modification)`) them, then applied web config modifications (`$ca.Parent.ApplyWebConfigModifications()`), updated central administration app (`$ca.Update`) and the parent app as well (`$ca.Parent.Update`).

After all this, I ran the configuration wizard again and there were no problems.